# How to show a loading page?

Tags: struts2

I have a Java application in which I provide a search box that users use to receive a long list of results. 
I need to show a page while user is waiting for the response to be back from server, I know that I can send the request using ajax and while the response is not back I can show a lightbox or a separate page but I am wondering if there is any other way to implement it without ajax as I do not care if it is asynchronous or not. 
I suppose need to use interceptors but do not know how and could not find much info.

Comment: what is the downvote for ? Sorry I am not a mind reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the loading page usign struts2 you need to use execAndWait intereceptor. Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-execandwait-interceptor-example/)